# WPF Popup tab key bug

Tags: wpf, popup, focus, tab-ordering

I have a WPF Popup control with a ListBox and a Button in it. When I click the `Button`, it should become disabled. The problem is, that when I disable the Button, the Tab key goes out from the Popup. I tried to set the focus to the ListBox, after I set the Button's `IsEnabled` to false, but that did not work. So, how can I set the tab focus to the ListBox inside the Popup control ?

Here is my code.

Window1.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Name="openButton" Content="Open"/>
        <Popup Name="popup" Placement="Center">
            <StackPanel>
                <ListBox Name="listBox"/>
                <Button Name="newItemsButton" Content="New Items"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Window1.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication5
{
    partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            openButton.Focus();
            listBox.ItemsSource = new string[] { "Item1", "Item2", "Item3" };
            listBox.SelectedIndex = 1;

            openButton.Click += delegate { popup.IsOpen = true; };
            popup.Opened += delegate { FocusListBox(); };
            newItemsButton.Click += delegate
            {
                newItemsButton.IsEnabled = false;
                FocusListBox();
            };
        }

        void FocusListBox()
        {
            var i = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(
                listBox.SelectedIndex) as ListBoxItem;
            if (i != null)
                Keyboard.Focus(i);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a screenshot:

[alt text http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/6305/popuptabkey.png](http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/6305/popuptabkey.png)

**Later Edit:**

I've found a workaround, that is to delay the `FocusListBox();` call as below:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(FocusListBox), DispatcherPriority.Input);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define an explicit focus scope by setting the [FocusManager.IsFocusScope property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.isfocusscope.aspx) on the Popup:

```
<Popup FocusManager.IsFocusScope="true">
  <!-- your content here -->
</Popup>
```

This will keep the focus from moving back out to controls within the containing element.

Comment: KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" does nothing.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it's about focus scope. Tested it, it works, revised my answer.

Comment: FYI, when I tested it, I had left your code-behind exactly as you supplied it (with the explict call to Focus the list box). Realizing this, I went back and removed it and the focus still jumps out of the Popup which is very strange. For now at least it will keep you from having to use a timer to delay setting the focus.